# How do I add blend file to my question?

Tags: discussion

I'm new here and I want to provide my work in my questions, but I don't know how. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

open blend-exchange.com and follow instructions

Comment: That's odd! It works fine from my desktop and looks ok if I hover over it in Firefox although I agree that it's showing a non-existant page if I click it. :^( I'll delete my comment and see if I can figure out what's going on. Thanks for the heads-up!